# how to use if else in php for two check box

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

If signal variable post but its go in 3rd condition
This code every condition work condition 3rd not follow any condition

```
print_r($_POST);
$id =$this->input->post('id');
$v_v=$this->input->post("d_v");
$v_d=$this->input->post("d_d");

if(isset($v_d) && !isset($v_v)){
    echo "a";
}elseif(!isset($v_d) && isset($v_v) ){
    echo "b";
}elseif(isset($v_v) && isset($v_d)){
    echo "c";
}elseif (!isset($v_v) && !isset($v_d)){
    echo "d";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/index/home_email_update" method="POST">
    <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
    <?php
        if ($f['subscription_discount_voucher']== 1){
    ?>
    <div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_v"  value="0" id="textfield"> Unsubscribe from Discount Voucher Emails.</div>
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>  
    <div class="email"><input type="checkbox"  name="d_v"  value="1" id="textfield"> Subscribe from Discount Voucher Emails.</div>
    <?php
        }
        if($f['subscribe_daily_deal']==1){
    ?>

    <div class="email">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="d_d" value="0" id="textfield">
        Unsubscribe from Daily Deal Emails.
    </div>  
    <?php
        }else{
    ?>
    <div class="email">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="d_d" value="1" id="textfield"> 
        Subscribe from Daily Deal Emails.
    </div>  
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <div class="email_1">
        <input type="submit" class="submit_new" value="Change">
    </div>  
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening, and what do you expect to happen? As it is, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Why on Earth is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: this code show every time 3rd condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **isset** (more https://www.php.net/isset) in this condition.

```
$v_d = 0;
var_dump(isset($v_d)); //return TRUE;
```

**isset** will return FALSE only if $v_d will be NULL.

So you should check incoming values.

```
if($v_d && $v_v === 0){
```

e.t.c

**EDIT**:

Note that in CodeIgniter **$this->input->post("d_d")** will return NULL if **d_d** is not submited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use This;

```
if(isset($_POST['d_d']) && !isset($_POST['d_v'])){
    echo "a";
}elseif(!isset($_POST['d_d']) && isset($_POST['d_v']) ){
    echo "b";
}elseif(isset($_POST['d_v']) && isset($_POST['d_d'])){
    echo "c";
}elseif (!isset($_POST['d_v']) && !isset($_POST['d_d'])){
    echo "d";
}
```

Comment: every time true 3rd condtion